# How to get table name using row value?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name like 'order_id')
```

Using column name i'm getting table name.

Is it possible to get table name using row value, like i have one table order contains orderid, using orderid value is it possible to fetch table name in a database

Comment: Not easily. Why would you want to do this anyway? If you wanted to do this then I imagine you would need to use dynamic SQL, and also to have some limitations? For example, let's say you look for "donkey" or "12345", would you only want to check text columns for the first case, and only integer columns for the second? Could you assume that you were always checking columns with a postfix of "_id", etc.?

Comment: searching fixed value '2ahgdfasd' like this

Comment: what on earth is the use case for this? Is it a workaround to some terrible database design?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had to do something similar. This is the script I used (if you are using SQL Server).

Please keep in mind that this will take a very long time depending on your database. You can restrict the tables or schemas at will by reviewing the query on the cursor. You can also edit it to do a `LIKE` search instead of an equal (`=`). It might also need to filter by column type if you have `BLOB` or other data types that can't be compared with strings.

```
DECLARE @v_TextToSearch VARCHAR(100) = 'YourSearchValue'


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FoundColumns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #FoundColumns

CREATE TABLE #FoundColumns (
    SchemaName VARCHAR(200),
    TableName VARCHAR(200),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(200))


DECLARE @c_SchemaName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @c_TableName VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        SchemaName = QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id)),
        TableName = QUOTENAME(T.name)
    FROM
        sys.tables AS T
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @c_SchemaName, @c_TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @c_ColumnName VARCHAR(200)

    DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            ColumnName = QUOTENAME(C.name)
        FROM
            sys.tables AS T
            INNER JOIN sys.columns AS C ON C.object_id = T.object_id
        WHERE
            QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id)) = @c_SchemaName AND
            QUOTENAME(T.name) = @c_TableName
        ORDER BY
            C.name

    OPEN ColumnCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @c_ColumnName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @v_DynamicSQLInsert VARCHAR(MAX) = '

            INSERT INTO #FoundColumns (
                SchemaName,
                TableName,
                ColumnName)
            SELECT
                SchemaName = ''' + @c_SchemaName + ''',
                TableName = ''' + @c_TableName + ''',
                ColumnName = ''' + @c_ColumnName + ''' 
            WHERE
                EXISTS (
                    SELECT
                        1
                    FROM
                        ' + @c_SchemaName + '.' + @c_TableName + ' AS T
                    WHERE
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), T.' + @c_ColumnName + ') = ''' + @v_TextToSearch + ''')'

        EXEC (@v_DynamicSQLInsert)

        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @c_ColumnName

    END

    CLOSE ColumnCursor
    DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @c_SchemaName, @c_TableName

END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor


SELECT
    F.SchemaName,
    F.TableName,
    F.ColumnName
FROM
    #FoundColumns AS F
ORDER BY
    F.SchemaName,
    F.TableName,
    F.ColumnName
```